# Integration involving trigonometric functions

Tags: calculus, integration

Integrate
$$\int \frac{1}{\cos x + \tan x} \, \mbox{d}x$$

I tried to look for an expression (mostly) an identity which correlates cos and tan but to no avail.

Comment: Express in terms of sines and cosines, simplify a bit, and what to do may become clear.

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite:

$$\frac{1}{\cos x + \tan x} = \frac{1}{\cos x + \frac{\sin x}{\cos x}} = \frac{\cos x}{\cos^2 x +\sin x} = \frac{\cos x}{1-\sin^2 x +\sin x}$$
Now $t = \sin x$ could work; you'll get a rational integrand.